# When to use QueueUserAPC()?

Tags: c, multithreading, winapi

I *do* understand what an APC *is*, how it works, and how *Windows* uses it, but I don't understand when I (as a programmer) should use [`QueueUserAPC`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684954.aspx) instead of, say, a fiber, or thread pool thread.

When should I choose to use `QueueUserAPC`, and why?

Comment: It is the low-level equivalent of the Windows message loop.  It lets you inject code into a thread in a safe way.  The thread signals that it is ready to deal with re-entrancy by executing an alertable wait.  Like calling GetMessage().

Comment: @HansPassant: Hmmm... I guess so, but I don't quite see how it's like GetMessage(). GetMessage simply retrieves a message, whereas QueueUserAPC *calls* the method -- so it could cause a stack overflow, right? They seem to be different...

Comment: Just want remember everyone that "GetMessage" is NOT an alertable wait. And @Mehrdad, no QueueUserAPC will not call the method until the thread is ready to handle them which is always explicit in the source code

Comment: @Lothar: Wow, exactly 4 years later :) I don't understand how what you're saying has anything to do with the stack overflow I'm talking about...

Comment: Stackoverflow is now a knowledge base. It fails badly at the moment as a Q&A site. But this is one of the top answers when you search for APC. So i think we can continue to comment. And the normal message loop is one of the first trap people fail for when using APC based on questions here and in other forums.

Comment: @Lothar: I just realized you weren't replying to the same part of my comment that I thought. (I thought you were replying to my question about the stack overflow, but it seems like you were correcting the part before that.) Yes, I see what you intended to say now. And yes, I probably shouldn't have said that `QueueUserAPC` "calls" the method, since as you said, it doesn't actually do that; an alertable wait does. Thanks for clarifying. However, my point about the stack overflow was exactly that one would expect the alertable wait calling it to overflow the stack; I just phrased it poorly.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`QueueUserAPC` is a neat tool that can often be a shortcut for some tasks that are otherwise handled with synchronization objects. It allows you to tell a particular thread to do something whenever it is convenient for that thread (i.e. when it finishes its current work and starts waiting on something).

Let's say you have a main thread and a worker thread. The worker thread opens a socket to a file server and starts downloading a 10GB file by calling recv() in a loop. The main thread wants to have the worker thread do something else in its downtime while it is waiting for net packets; it can queue a function to be run on the worker while it would otherwise be waiting and doing nothing.

You have to be careful with APCs, because as in the scenario I mentioned you would not want to make another blocking WinSock call (which would result in undefined behavior). You really have to be watching in order to find any good uses of this functionality because you can do the same thing in other ways. For example, by having the other thread check an event every time it is about to go to sleep, rather than giving it a function to run while it is waiting. Obviously the APC would be simpler in this scenario.

It is like when you have a call desk employee sitting and waiting for phone calls, and you give that person little tasks to do during their downtime. "Here, solve this Rubik's cube while you're waiting." Although, when a phone call comes in, the person would not put down the Rubik's cube to answer the phone (the APC has to return before the thread can go back to waiting).

`QueueUserAPC` is also useful if there is a single thread (Thread A) that is in charge of some data structure, and you want to perform some operation on the data structure from another thread (Thread B), but you don't want to have the synchronization overhead / complexity of trying to share that data between two threads. By having Thread B queue the operation to run on Thread A, which solely maintains that structure, you are executing any arbitrary function you want on that data without having to worry about synchronization.

It is just another tool like a thread pool. However with a thread pool you cannot send a task to a particular thread. You have no control over where the work is done. When you queue up a task that may end up creating a whole new thread. You may queue two tasks and they get done simultaneously on two different threads. With `QueueUserAPC`, you can be guaranteed that the tasks would get done in order and on the thread you designate.